# what is the facebook ajax request which get the posts?

Tags: ajax, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, scrapy

I am trying using facebook from Scrapy.

I can log in successfully. However, I can't get the posts on facebook because the posts comes from ajax calls.

I tried using firebug and check the XHR. I got this:

[image]

I tried to check the response of all those request but none of them contains the actual data of the posts.

What is the ajax request that get the posts on facebook?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What kinds of post, who is fetching, be specific; and add some code that you've used

Comment: @SahilMittal there is no code buddy, the code starts with the url. When you konw the url for the ajax call, you can call that url and get the resuls from you spider. However, the posts that I am looking for are the posts by pages that I have liked before. Also, to answer your second question, I am fetching this data from scrapy.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the AJAX calls from your browser. Those are encrypted since Facebook uses HTTPS connections. Focus on using their API to make the calls you need to get the data you want. That's the entire purpose of their [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/post).

Comment: I am using scrapy to get information. So I need to use ajax calls. Also, I am using it not from browsers but from python.

Comment: Python can request URLs and parse them, their API is not restricted to Javascript only. I believe it's `urllib`.. you can use the `cURL` examples they provide, and adapt your code to match the format used.